# Wrong center of screen coordinates

Tags: java, android

I'm coding an Android game and I'm trying to put the character in the middle of the screen (X axis).

In order to get the middle of the screen I get the screen width withe the following command:

```
int phoneWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Then I divide phoneWidth by two and hoped that the character would appear in the middle of the screen but it appears slightly to the right.

This is the code that I use:

```
public void drawCharacter() {
        charImg = new Texture("pika.PNG");
        charSprite = new Sprite(charImg);
        float ahaha = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        charPosX = (float)phoneWidth/ 2;
    }

@Override
    public void render() {
        ch.stop();
        double elapsedSeconds = ch.getSeconds();

        checkLevel();
        handleObstacles();

        scrollTimer = scrollTimer + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 2;
        if (scrollTimer > 1.0f)
            scrollTimer = 0.0f;

        sprite.setV(scrollTimer);
        sprite.setV2(scrollTimer + 2);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        charSprite.setPosition(charPosX, charPosY);
        for (int i = 0; i < obstacles.size(); i++) {
            obstacleSprites.get(i).setPosition(obstacles.get(i).getPosX(), obstacles.get(i).getPosY());
        }

        spriteBatch.begin();
        sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        charSprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        for (int i = 0; i < obstacleSprites.size(); i++) {
            obstacleSprites.get(i).draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        spriteBatch.end();

        moveCharacter();
        moveObstacle();
    }
```

Does anyone know where this error come from?

Comment: Please further describe the error with the drawing. Is the x or y position off? or both? Also...depending on using fullscreen, statusbar and / or using a toolbar, these are possible sources for an `y` offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand edge of your sprite will be in the middle of the screen.

Subtract half the sprite width from half the screen width to draw the sprite centered horizontally.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I thought that by default the character would be drawn by the center. Thanks.